# C++ - condition in -for loop- isn't evaluated as I think it should be

Tags: c++, for-loop

I'm quite new to C++ and I have some kind of problem. I would like to ask if someone could explain to me why the evaluation within the for condition does not work.

This is a part of a program I've written, there is a rpm value which is given by the user and gets assorted to a rpm_case to do some calculations later.

What it SHOULD do:

- rpm between 800 up to 1200 ==> rpm_case = 0
- rpm between 1200 up to 1800 ==> rpm_case = 1
- rpm between 1800 up to 2500 ==> rpm_case = 2
- rpm between 2500 to 3500 ==> rpm_case = 3

========================================================================

in the first place I had some 30-line long if-construction for that but I discarded that already  and replaced it with the following much shorted and nicer way to write it (this works as expected):

```
const float rpm_bases[known_rpm_bases] = {800, 1200, 1800, 2500, 3500};
short rpm_case;
for (rpm_case=0;; rpm_case++) {
    if (!(rpm > rpm_bases[rpm_case+1])) {break;}
}
```

but I'm still not happy because I was really trying to get rid of the if with the for loop. 
But the for- loop instead always loops over the entire size of the array instead breaking at the considered point.

```
const float rpm_bases[known_rpm_bases] = {800, 1200, 1800, 2500, 3500};
short rpm_case;
for (rpm_case=0; (!(rpm > rpm_bases[rpm_case+1])); rpm_case++) {}
```

?? It somehow seems as it is not possible to evaluate a array with the counter-variable within the conditional part of an for-loop??? Or am I just doing something totally wrong I don't want to exclude that option either.

Big Thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: As far as I remember, the RHS of  the conditional part of the for loop gets evaluated only once. Not very sure. Just try replacing that condition with a function that returns a different value each time, but prints the value before returning. `for(i=0;i<f(); ++i) {}; int f() {int r=randint(); print(r); return r;}`

Comment: In your first sample, you define a condition to _leave_ the loop (when `true`) but the 2nd expression of `for` is considered to _stay_ in the loop (when `true`). So, I guess your actual mistake is that you didn't revert your condition in the second sample. (i.e. removing the `!` should make the behavior of your 2nd sample equivalent to the first.)

Comment: @Nav: No, the loop condition is evaluated (in its entirety) on each iteration. However, I applaud your suggested method of testing your hypothesis!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The middle expression of a `for` statement is the condition that must be true for the loop to repeat. Therefore, it must be the opposite of the condition that must be true for the loop to break.

For this reason, you must negate the expression by removing the `!` (NOT) operator, like this:

`for (rpm_case=0; rpm > rpm_bases[rpm_case+1]; rpm_case++);`

This expression will work for the cases stated in your question. However, if `rpm` is higher than 3500, it will cause the array `rpm_bases` to be accessed out of bounds, causing [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Therefore, it would be safer to write the loop in the following way:

```
for ( rpm_case=0; rpm_case < known_rpm_bases; rpm_case++ )
{
    if ( rpm <= rpm_bases[rpm_case] ) break;
}
```

That way, your program will just give you an additional increment of `rpm_case` if `rpm` is higher than the highest value, instead of accessing the array out of bounds causing undefinied behavior.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the problem. The moment I started to try to THINK through the actual condition to exit/remain in the loop it was clear.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is effectively just a typo.

The loop condition is for how long the loop *does* keep running, not to describe when it ends.

Invert it.